# When would you use purity as a measure of external validity over entropy?

Tags: clustering, text-mining, entropy

This question particularly pertains to text clustering. I've not really found anything on why one would use purity over entropy or vice versa. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: by purity do you mean Gini impurity

Comment: https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html

Comment: what is that about purity

Comment: I'm not sure if your trying to help me or troll me here.

Comment: @develarist asked you if you meant Gini impurity. Instead of answering yes or no you gave a link to a book which seemed an unusual response.

Comment: Ok, Gini impurity is not the same thing as purity. That url linked describes purity much better than I could, but it's basically an external evaluation criterion of cluster quality. It is the percent of the total number of objects(data points) that were classified correctly, in the unit range [0..1]. They are two different things.